# Where are location settings stored on KitKat?

Tags: android-source

I'm building KitKat using AOSP and would like Location setting to be set to "High accuracy" by default and without any user intervention.

I've read various bits and pieces on how it's typically done and can trigger a dialog to present to the user, but I'd like to avoid any user interactivity.

I'm thinking that if this setting is stored in one of the .xml files in the system, perhaps I could have an app that modifies it upon startup. Or perhaps tweak the AOSP code directly to make it default to High accuracy.

Thanks in advance for your thoughts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to do this by modifying the AOSP code directly.